# Travelling as a US citizen with a stopover in Brazil

Tags: visas, us-citizens, transit, brazil, stopovers

As US citizen, does one still need Brazilian transit visa, if travelling to another South-American country (eg. Argentina) with stopover in any of Brazilian airports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The US citizens are required to have expensive visas to Brazil in "reciprocation" for US visas for Brazilians. Even if there is a stopover, a transit visa is required.

As far as I know, that the **only exception of this rule is São Paulo-Guarulhos Airport**. If your stopover is there, and you don't leave airport (don't try to go trough customs), you don't need transit visa. But only in this one airport.

A friend of mine was travelling from Miami to Buenos Aires. He was misinformed by his airline and had stopover in Brasília. **He was deported for not having a transit visa**.

Comment: What did the deportation mean in practice? Did they send him back to Miami instead of Buenos Aires?

Comment: He was sent back to Miami and then get another flight with stopover in Guarulhos (that was paid by airline, because of their fault).

Comment: Is that GRU airport that has the exception?

Comment: I'm at GRU airport now, and I can confirm that international connections do not have to go through immigration.  No visa?  No problem (:

Comment: This outdated , US passport does not need a visa to Brazil